# How do I replicate the Recent Tasks/Apps button in Android Marshmallow?

Tags: android, navbar, android-recents

This works perfectly on Lollipop:

```
recents_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            Intent intent = new Intent ("com.android.systemui.recents.SHOW_RECENTS");
            intent.setComponent (new ComponentName ("com.android.systemui", "com.android.systemui.recents.RecentsActivity"));
            startActivity (intent);
        }
```

But on Marshmallow I get:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=com.android.systemui.recents.SHOW_RECENTS cmp=com.android.systemui/.recents.RecentsActivity } from ProcessRecord{96f7c1e 4931:com.myapp/u0a188} (pid=4931, uid=10188) not exported from uid 10043
```

Comment: It looks like they no longer make that available for third parties. I cannot say that I am surprised by this.

Answer (score 2):

You can see that intent is [not exported](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/marshmallow-release/packages/SystemUI/AndroidManifest.xml) by Marshmallow, while it [was exported](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/kitkat-release/packages/SystemUI/AndroidManifest.xml) by KitKat.

Tasker is able to show the recent apps dialog, I don't know how it does it.